# Need help formatting date in PHP when variable is part of an array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I need to format my DATE field but I can't figure out how to do it with this specific scenario where the variable is part of an array.

I have read a lot of different PHP date format posts from many sources, but none address this format I'm using with the foreach output of the array specifically. Most posts seem to address the variable as either a lone variable or as a static date.

I have tried:

```
foreach ($employees as $row) { 
    echo "$row->firstname $row->lastname, date('m/Y', strtotime('$row->date_hired')).";
}
```

but this is the actual output:

> Mike Higgins, date('m/Y', strtotime('2013-01-09')).

I have a table with many fields and one of them is date_hired which is a DATE field which is saved like this YYYY-MM-DD.

```
firstname   |   lastname   |    date_hired
Mike        |   Higgins    |    2016-01-04
```

I query this table and get an ObjectList array full of fields:

```
$employees = "SELECT firstname, lastname, date_hired from employees ";
$db->setQuery( $employees ); 
$employees = $db->loadObjectList();
```

and then I output my data:

```
foreach ($employees as $row) { 
echo "$row->firstname $row->lastname, $row->date_hired.";
}
```

This of course will give me this: `Mike Higgins, 2016-01-04`.

But what I want is this: `Mike Higgins, Jan 4, 2016.`

Comment: `echo "...", date(...);` – You simply have to do it *outside* the string literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you want :

```
date('M d, Y', strtotime($row->date_hired))
```

Instead of :

```
date('m/Y', strtotime('$row->date_hired'))
```

The single quotes (`'`) around expression `$row->date_hired` prevent it from being interpreted as a variable (it becomes a string).

Also the proper date spec for your use case is `'M d, Y'`, which will return something like `Jan 4, 2016`.

Comment: I see my error now was in the syntax of the output - thanks!

Comment: Why would you need the single quotes at all? The date is a string in the variable anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
foreach ($employees as $row) { 
    echo "$row->firstname $row->lastname, ".date('m/Y', strtotime($row->date_hired));
}
```

I guess it will work too.

```
foreach ($employees as $row) { 
    echo $row->firstname." ".$row->lastname.", ".date("M j, Y", strtotime($row->date_hired));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ex:

```
echo date("M j, Y,", strtotime("2011-01-07"));
```

try

```
echo date("M j, Y,", strtotime($row->date_hired));
```